# "Let us know" or "Let us To know"?

Tags: complementation, bare-infinitives

Till today I thought that correct way is to say "let us **to** know", but today I received a formal email that was written there "Let us know", and that's why I'm here to check the issue.

I would also like to know if the answer depends on the type of pronoun, I mean if it matters that the pronoun is such as: *her*, *him*, *they* etc (*let her know, let him know, let they know* etc.)

Comment: I have never seen "to+infinitives" after "let" and "make" !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain verbs require "***to***-infinitive" when combined with another verb, and certain verbs omit the "***to***" in such situations.  For instance, "*make*" requires no particle "to" in the active voice, but in passive voice the "to" reappears:

> I'll **make** you **understand** this topic!
>   The students **were made to write** it all down.

Modal verbs *usually* take bare infinitives, but sometimes, in some situations, the particle "to" reappears, too.

> **Dare** I **say** more?  (*'dare' is the principal verb*)
>   How *did* he **dare to come** here alone?  (*'dare' is not the principal verb*)

---

The verb "let" is one that is rather simple - it always takes an infinitive ***without*** the 'to', regardless of the verb or the object (noun or pronoun):

> Let me **know**, please.   (*imperative mood*, *active voice*, *object = me*)
>   And you let them **rest**?   (*active voice*, *colloquial interrogative*, *object = them*)
>   The hostages were let **go**.   (*passive voice*, *no object*)

Comment: And the verb help, I think, can be added to the list !

Comment: @Cardinal: To which list?

Comment: make - let - help - and modals can be viewed as a list

Comment: @Cardinal, Yes, there is a whole lot of those.  You can find them on the web by looking for "verb-infinitive", for instance.